# Cant connect ot internet with latest version of ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ethernet

I want to be a frontweb developer and i was advised to install ubuntu. I've tried some ubuntu versions before (only live cds to try) but I never really like it. After a long day to even install ubuntu i finally got it done. But immediately I noticed that there was no internet --> cable unplugged. So I got back to windows and tried to find solution online. I managed to install the latest drivers of my mainboard utp port RealTek PCIe GBE Family Controller. Of course I still didnt got internet after installing them.

I also was quite furious about the grub2 and I really wanted to delete ubuntu and grub2. To do that I had to boot in to ubuntu once again (according to the internet). But now, miraculously, internet worked (i was so happy). I fooled around a bit and installed sublime text, localhost, github etc. Then i booted back to windows to play a game and after when I went back to finalize my ubuntu settings, internet FAILS AGAIN.

How can I fix this?

`Lspci -nnk`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0100] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:0100]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0112] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:0112]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1c3a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1c2d]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1892]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 [8086:1c1a] (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 [8086:1c1c] (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 [8086:1c1e] (rev b5)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1c26]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c44] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1c44]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller [8086:1c00] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1c00]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1c22]
00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller [8086:1c08] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1c08]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
02:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge [1b21:1080] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many) [1849:8168]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1b6f:7023] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:7023]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

`lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
usb_storage            62209  1 
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bluetooth             395423  10 bnep,rfcomm
joydev                 17381  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    61438  1 
snd_hda_intel          52355  3 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143060  0 
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55624  241 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  123 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
serio_raw              13462  0 
lpc_ich                21080  0 
snd                    69238  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82274  1 mei_me
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52616  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
i915                  783485  3 
psmouse               102222  0 
video                  19476  1 i915
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
drm_kms_helper         52758  1 i915
r8168                 400910  0 
drm                   302817  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
r8169                  67581  0 
mii                    13934  1 r8169
```

`lpconfig -a`

didnt work

`cat/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`cat/etc/resolv.config`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

EDIT:
Tried alot of solutions, nothing works. Ubuntu is even failing to execute 'sudo ./autorun.sh' it says no such command. As im looking on the internet for solutions, i found out that a lot of people have problems with this ethernet chipset r8168. No working solution has been posted yet though. Can someone add me on skype please and help me? Or is it better to buy a pci card that 100% works ( no realtek chipset of course), any thoughts on good and cheap ones that will work out of the box?
It is so odd that it only worked 1 time (and i didnt do anything for that)